# Safely methods removing

Tags: c#, resharper

I have huge solution, big 40 projects inside, BL, services layers, Repositories and mvc UI. I need to remove 2 controllers and all it's dependencies. Some methods inside these controllers call other methods , they call others, they call BL , they call services, they call respository. How to remove safely all these connection without destroying rest part?  Is there any quick way to do it ? maybe resharper can help ?

Comment: You can right-click solution and "View Project Dependencies" and for projects "Find Code dependent on Module" but it won't be as straight-forward as you expect, your solution is huge. Advice : backup your solution then test these features.

Comment: If you remove methods, they will no longer be called from the previous code, is that what you want?  Resharper will certainly do that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove your methods, build and see where you have errors, this will show you where your methods are used ;)